# Calling python functions in HTML file in Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I have a list of folders in my python file, and in an HTML file I iterate over the list to display the names of each folder on my page.

```
{% for folder in folders %}
<li><a href = {{folder}}> {{folder}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

What I am trying to do is make it so when you click on the folder, it will do the same thing, but inside the clicked folder. I have a function `open_folder` that takes one parameter (the clicked folder name), but my problem is that I don't really know how to call the function with a parameter in the HTML file. A lot of pages or tutorials I have seen only have the python files.  In my main file I also have the route as

```
/<route>/
```

I am new to Flask and was just wondering if anybody had examples for how to do this.  It would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean. I think what you should be doing is making a POST request to a view that takes the folder name. If you want the action of 'open_folder' to occur without making another request you will need to handle it in the browser with Javascript.

Comment: I think my open_folder method should be called in the post method, but as far as i know you call the post method like 
    method = post
and i need post to take a parameter.  I think the problem i may be having is the app route with <route> at theend always returns a 404 error, so i dont think I know how to use that correctly.  I am trying to figure out a lot so sorry if my explainations arent the best. still new. but thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the assumption that `folder` is something whose contents you'd want to return dynamically as its own page, the appropriate way to do this would be to have a separate route and view that handles folders. Something like the following:

```
@app.route("/folder/<folder_name>/")
def folder(folder_name):
    # do something with folder_name
    pass
```

And in your HTML you would link to it as follows:

```
<a href="{% url_for('folder', folder_name=folder) %}">{{ folder }}</a>
```

Obviously you'd want to update the route accordingly, depending on the contents of `folder`, but that's the "Flask way" of linking to dynamic content.

Comment: thanks! the link actually should be <br>
   <a href = "{{ url_for(... }}">   <br>
instead of {% %}, at least that is what worked for me.

Comment: No problem! I believe in Jinja `{{ }}` is to output values and `{% %}` is for Python logic, like `if` statements, loops and function calls. Perhaps they've doubled down to be graceful in case of accidental use of `{{ }}`.